# SFP, standard EEPROM?

Tags: sfp

I have a SFP compatible module which has an I2C interface. I understand that SFP is a pseudo-standard but I can't find any documentation on the I2C interface and what registers in the EEPROM do what.

My goal is to just reset the SFP over I2C and read back any error messages that I might have access to.

Product in question: https://www.fs.com/products/12626.html

Similar unanswered question: [Open Switch (OPX): Accessing SFP EEPROMs via I2C on a Dell S4112F-ON](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/73046/open-switch-opx-accessing-sfp-eeproms-via-i2c-on-a-dell-s4112f-on)

Comment: Do you understand that an EEPROM is read-only? That is what the RO stands for. With the proper equipment, you could erase it and rewrite it, but in your device, the data in it does not change.

Comment: In any case, your question is probably better suited for [electronics.se].

Comment: Hi Ron, I will re-post in EE. Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: Electrically Erasable **PROGRAMMABLE** Read Only Memory. 9 times out of 10, the SFP EEPROM *is* rewritable. (I've yet to encounter one that write-protected)

Comment: The document you seek is SFF-8472. There's no error log in the SFP. (DOM can show current signal levels.)